# Reducer returned undefined during initialization but am returning initialState as default in reducer switch

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am attempting to follow the instructions found in the [redux-persist docs](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/recipes.md) to delay the render until rehydration is complete, and I am now receiving this error

`"Reducer 'auth' returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined."`

However, I am defining and returning the initialState in my auth reducer as follows:

```
const initialState = {
    authenticated: false,
    authenticating: false,
    loginError: '',
}
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        ...my switch cases here

        default:
        return state
    }
}
```

I did not change how I am creating my store so I am not sure why I am now receiving this error. I will also include my store creation and combine reducers method below

```
const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    undefined,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk),
        autoRehydrate({ log: true }),
        window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : (f) => f
    )
)

export default class AppProvider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      rehydrated: false,
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    persistStore(store, {storage: AsyncStorage}, () => {
      this.setState({ rehydrated: true })
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.rehydrated) {
      return <ActivityIndicator />
    }
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
      <App/>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

My reducers export file

```
export default reducers = combineReducers({
    auth,
    connection,
    initialLoad,
    queue,
})
```

Comment: I think the problem is you are passing `undefined` as the preloaded state on store creation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be something on your store creation. The [F8App](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app) is a good reference for this.

You can do the following:

```
// configureStore.js
// ... imports

const middlewares = [thunk, promise, array];
var createAppStore = applyMiddleware(...middlewares)(createStore);

export default configureStore = (onComplete) => {
    const store = autoRehydrate()(createAppStore)(reducers);
    persistStore(store, { storage: AsyncStorage }, onComplete);
    return store;
}


// AppProvider.js
// ...
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            store: configureStore(() => {
                this.setState({ isLoading: false });
            }),
        };
    }
    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return <ActivityIndicator />;
        }
        return (
            <Provider store={this.state.store}>
                <App />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The main cause is that you pass in undefined as the preloaded state. Just pass in your root reducer and middlewares and the error should disappear

```
const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk),
        autoRehydrate({ log: true }),
        window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : (f) => f
    )
)
```

Also, It is complaining that auth is undefined, so you should make sure that all of your reducers are imported correctly in the root reducer `reducers`.

Comment: I removed undefined as the preloaded state but still receiving the error

Comment: Yes. So I went into my reducer and changed the default return from `default: return state` to `default: return { ...state }` and so far it seems to be working.. Do you know why this would this affect anything?

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, `{ ...state }` is exactly the same as `state` because you are not adding anything after the spread operator.

Comment: I agree there is no difference but it removes the error which confuses me. None of my other reducers return the default state like this but they work.

Comment: Can you try changing the name of the reducer from `reducer` to `auth` in your auth reducer?

Comment: So inside one of my action creators, I had a condition inside a function that relied on a boolean inside another reducer state, so I was importing store inside the auth reducer and doing `if (store.getState().otherReducer.condition)`. After removing the store import and the conditional it works without the spread operator.